# For java, which is more useful Eclipse OR Netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I am new to java and I listen about net beans and eclipse IDE both, But i am confused about which one I should use. Can anyone tell me why net beans use and why eclipse use. and which is better to use.
I want to know about which is user friendly and easy to use.

Comment: You're asking if the color green is better or worse than blue, and why.  You should understand that there is no real answer to such a broad and ill-defined question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `IDE` if you're a Java beginner. You have to write code with a text editor (nodepad) and compile  and run in a command shell using `javac.exe` and `java.exe`.

Have a look at articles

1. [Top Java Developers Offer Advice to Students/Java beginner.](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/studentdevs/index.html)
2. [IDE vs Command Line](http://www.coderanch.com/t/478969/java/java/ide-vs-command-line)

Comment: That's probably the lamest piece of advice ever posted on any of the stack exchange sites, ever.  And the article you referred to does not suggest anything like that.  My advice: learn to write a "hello, world" program with notepad, compile it and run it from the command line, and once you have done that once, immediately move on to an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

It is preference. And you should try to avoid just using notepad. You will just end up spamming threads or asking too many questions about why you are getting errors and where you are getting them.

I personally use both. I use Eclipse some days and Netbeans for others. Both are equally good and equally bad. They both have things that the other lack.

Personally, I would recommend Eclipse, I found it easier to start with because it was simple, and the coloring systems on it weren't as weird as Netbean's.

Once again it is preference. I only started with eclipse because I found it easier to concentrate with the coloring system.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly a matter of taste. Try to learn the language first instead of a given tool. Once you learn the language, try both tools (Eclipse and Netbeans) and see which one you like best. You can also try also learning a good text editor (emacs or vim). It is a long road ahead. Enjoy the ride.